# Cantaloupe Island by Herbie Hancock

Tags: chords, jazz

In Cantaloupe Island by Herbie Hancock, the first measure is said to be Fm7. Now, we have a lot of notes that is not a part of the chord (non-chordal tones). How then can we say that this is Fm7?

I have also seen this chord written as "F-". Is this the way some people write chords in this genre?

Comment: F- is a way to write F minor, probably from NNS. That should make Fm7 = F-7. Sounds to me like the majority of notes played over it are from the F, Ab, C and Eb pool.

Answer (score 3):

> How then can we say that this is an Fm7?

That's just our best evaluation of the situation. This is the not-so-secret truth behind music theory: it does not absolutely dictate or categorize music in all cases. It's just a guide and framework to help us communicate about musical ideas, but many musical ideas defy the conventions of music theory, and in those cases people just come as close as they can.

With ideas that don't totally fit, different people will come up with different approximations. So you have found a source that says the first measure is closest to Fm7, which just means one person sees it that way. Another person may feel the 7th degree doesn't really match with the surrounding structure and they might say it should be considered an Fm chord. Or some of the other notes might be squeezed into the chord name and it could become an Fm7add15 or who knows what.

A big takeway from this is that it doesn't pay to get too bogged down in the theory. Music theory is invaluable for analyzing, understanding, and communicating musical ideas, but the actual music is always the true source and the real message.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I wouldn't say that this is exactly in Fm7. Fm7 could be played on top of the melody, and it would sound good. Here's why:

- (1st beat) First chord is clearly Fm: F, Ab, C.
- (2nd and 3rd beat) Bb and D are passing notes that go to C and Eb respectively. The bass is C and the chord could be Cm (no5), that sounds good over the F minor chord, because it's like a Fm7 without the root and the third.
- (4th beat) Eb+F as bass -> minor 7th and root, and again Bb and D as passing tones that go to Ab and C and form the Fminor chord.

This is the way I would say this part goes, harmonically.

Like mentioned above, these notes make the F Dorian Mode.

> How then can we say that this is Fm7?

When you are composing a song, you'll have to use notes out of the harmony of the chord, otherwise it would sound boring. Using these kind of passing tones, creates a slight dissonance, that resolves to something consonant and makes it ok.

The F-7 is an alternative to the Fm7 notation; it's not used only in Jazz. It's quite common.

Comment: Seems to me that modal stuff is often considered not to need a key sig., but it will all belong to a certain 'key'. We us the same key sig. for Ionian/Aeolian, so why not for other modes?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it is this: the root is definitely F. What is happening on top is a standard F dorian pattern. The basic seventh chord in F dorian is Fm7, so in a lead sheet when you want to write down a simple harmony, the best choice is Fm7. You're of course right that this chord is implicit, but out of all basic seventh chords with root F, the only one that *can* be played over that pattern is Fm7.

Answer (score 1):

You have two things going on here. In general, it's given the chord Fm7 because that's the general quality of the A section. You can tell by the bass line, which is 1 5 7 8 — three out of four of the notes of the Fm7 (lacking only the third, which is given to you by the right hand).

That said, the scale is an F dorian scale, so it's OK to have those passing notes (Bb and D). This is what gives it it's distinct bluesy texture. If you just played an Fm7 chord repeatedly, it wouldn't feel like Cantaloupe Island because it doesn't have the sound created by that repetitive piano riff. ("All Blues" by Miles Davis has a similar vibe to it, but major key)

That's just the way of it with some songs — the harmony doesn't define the song. Like, if you wanted to play "Enter Sandman" by Metallica, you'd want to hear that guitar riff, not just an Em harmony. It wouldn't be recognizable without the distinctive musical elements.

Comment: How did you find out that it's F dorian?

Comment: It's the first four measures. The notes you're using are F, Ab, Bb, C, D, Eb, and F — the only note that's missing is the G, but you can kind of assume it because a flat 2 is so rare. So that's the dorian scale! When it changes to the Db7 chord, you're going to use a slightly different scale — Db Mixolydian (or F blues scale also works). It's such a great song because it hangs out on each chord system long enough for you to really get the hang of what scale you're using...